# Android Firebase Checking if Data is Equal To String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to store information into the database to store favorites. I basically have a listview and when you click on an item it will take you to a new activity. I want to be able to check if the item of the activity is equal to the itemName in my databse it will change the button text. My tree looks like this

-UserID:

--"Favorites":

---"ItemName" : {name:value}

How can I check if the item name of the activity I clicked on is equal to the item name in my database? I have this code below but it is not working.

```
private void checkifFavExist() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
   if ((myRef.child("Favorites").child(itemName.toLowerCase())).equals(itemName.toLowerCase())) {
        button_fav.setText("Remove From Favorites");
        removefavs();
    } else {
        button_fav.setText("Add to Favorites");
        addfavs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 if ((myRef.child("Favorites").child(itemName.toLowerCase())).equals(itemName.toLowerCase())) {
```

To this:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
Query queries=myRef.child("ItemName").orderByChild("name").equals(itemName);
```

You need to use `orderByChild("name").equals(itemName)` to check if the child in the database has that value. Also the `child(child_here)` needs to be the same name as in the database.

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)

Comment: Thanks, I had to add a value event listener but it worked